# How to set custom attribute labels for nested inputs in Laravel

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to get custom labels in the error messages. My inputs are nested and i am able to validate them using dot notation (e.g. `POLICY.HOLDER.NAME` ). They have to be nested and all caps to match the db structure so I can easily mass assign them.

Using the same notation in `'attributes' => ['POLICY.HOLDER.NAME' => 'Policy Holder']` in `resources/lang/en/validation.php` yielded no result.

I'm just trying to get them to match the labels i've set in the form.

app/Http/Controllers/OfferController.php (just the interesting part)

```
public function postOffer(OfferRequest $request) { //
    $post_data = $request->all();
    if (isset($post_data['POLICY'])) {
        // code to get data from $_POST and assign to models
    }
}
```

app/Http/Requests/OfferRequest.php

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request, Auth;

class OfertaRequest extends Request
{

    public function authorize() {
        return Auth::check();
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'POLICY.HOLDER.NAME' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function forbiddenResponse()
    {
        return Response::make('Permission denied foo!', 403);
    }

}
```

resources/lang/en/validation.php

```
'attributes' => [
    'POLICY.HOLDER.NAME' => 'Some custom string here...',
],
```

As you can see i've tried adding the input name in the Custom Validation Attributes array with no success. Here's the error message i get when leaving the input blank:

> The p o l i c y. h o l d e r. n a m e field is required.

Note the spaces. I've tried that too, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you add the code for what you've tried so far? E.g. controller, view, validation code

Comment: @JamesFlight i've added code

Comment: People on the PHP chatroom here on SO said it could be a laravel bug because of the uppercase input names. If i change to lowercase it no longer puts those spaces and the placeholder works. Unfortunately i have to have those in uppercase because the model attributes and DB columns have to... Comes from further up the chain of command and i don't have a say in this :))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Explicitly declare it as nested arrays:

```
'attributes' => [
    'POLICY' => [
        'HOLDER' => [
            'NAME' => 'Some custom string here...',
        ]
    ]
],
```

Comment: I would have never thought of that, works as expected. Thanks a bunch!