# Laravel Validation custom messages using nested attributes

Tags: laravel

I would like to ask for some advices about Laravel Validation...

Let's say I've got an input named `invoiceAddress[name]` and in a controller I've got a rule

```
$rule = ['invoiceAddress.name' => 'required',];
```

or just a

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'invoiceAddress.name' => 'required',
]);
```

now, inside custom validation language file `validation.php`, am I able to nest attributes somehow? like:

```
'required' => ':attribute is mandatory',

'attributes' => [
    'invoiceAddress' => [
        'name' => 'blahblah'
    ],
],
```

If I try to nest the attribute the way above, i get

```
ErrorException
    mb_strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

because I am using a field (as above)

```
['name' => 'blahblah']
```

I am trying to get custom messages using the file and the `:attribute` directive (as mentioned in the code above).

I am basically trying to do this [How to set custom attribute labels for nested inputs in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761230/how-to-set-custom-attribute-labels-for-nested-inputs-in-laravel) but i get the mentioned error...

Thank you in advance...

Comment: what is validation.php what are you trying to achieve are you having problem in message of validation?

Comment: validation.php is my custom validation language file and I am trying to get a message using defined attributes and `:attribute` directive ... instead of defining hundreds of custom messages

Comment: This issue still exists, have you found any valid solution?

Answer (score 2):

A Note On Nested Attributes

If your HTTP request contains "nested" parameters, you may specify them in your validation rules using "dot" syntax:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'author.name' => 'required',
    'author.description' => 'required',
]);
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic  (A Note On Nested Attributes Section)

Comment: I am sorry, i forgot to specific my goal - I want to get custom messages using custom validation language file... and using the `:attribute` directive inside the file...

Comment: reference: [https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-error-messages]

Comment: So you already solved custom validation message or need any help?

Comment: I am basically trying to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761230/how-to-set-custom-attribute-labels-for-nested-inputs-in-laravel but i get the mentioned ErrorException @SumonMahmud

Comment: check it i think i would be helpful for you. 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/validation-nested-attributes-and-nice-names

Comment: thank you but that's the same solution as on the link i mentioned in my previous comment... and trying to use nested array but i get the `ErrorException: mb_strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` @SumonMahmud

Comment: are you sure you're getting nested attributes from form? pls debug and ensure it.

Comment: the question want to know how add custom validation in nested input NOT laravel preserve validation